# MS Access - Passing fields in reports

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have a report that produces twelve pages, one for each month of the year. The report's main query contains the month name.

Below it is a subquery that can have more than one row in it. Right now the content of the subquery is identical on all twelve pages. But that's not what I want.

Is it possible to 'grab' the month name from the main report's query and use it in the subquery? In other words, I want the month name to be relected in the subquery on each page.

My online research says no, but I'm hoping an expert knows better.

Answer (score 0):

Use the *MasterLinkFields* and *ChildLinkFields* of the *subreport control* to filter the *subreport*.

And use the *month value* (1 to 12) to filter, not the month name as this is localised.